# Keep looping if the input is invalid

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a newbie to shell scripting and a beginner in programming. I have a scenario here that i would like to ask. I had part of the script pasted below, it is part of a case switch.

```
echo -n "Delete Source File After Encryption : [Y|N] "
read DSFE

if [ $DSFE = "Y" -o $DSFE = "y" ]; then
  Do something;
  clear

elif [ $DSFE = "N" -o $DSFE = "n" ]; then 
  Do something;
  clear
```

I like to find out how I can code the above snippet so that if the user input is not Y or N, it will loop and prompt the question.

Any comment on this mattter?

Thank you.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Were you the one to post [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118187/is-there-a-goto-like-command-in-unix) a while back?

Comment: The question linked above suits your case perfectly!

Comment: No. Thank you. Will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
until [[ $DSFE == [YyNn] ]]; do
        read -p "Delete Source File After Encryption? [Y|N] " DSFE
done

case $DSFE in
        [Yy]) do_something ;;
        [Nn]) do_something_else ;;
        *)    # this code should not be reached
esac
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian for solving my problem. It works like charm for me.

Comment: @Kevin Glad I could help and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to learn a bit how the system here works :-)